# Is there any way to create a SideDrawer in one Component and use it in multiple paces(Components) in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript-angular

I am developing an app using NativeScript. I want to use RadSideDrawer. Whatever I understood from nativescript.org is that I have to write same code snippet in every component where I want to display drawer. Is this a good practice? Or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: which NativeScript project did you use? (Angular, typescript or ..)

Comment: @miladfm Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You can use a component with content projection to show dynamic content.
2- You can use routing with `page-router-outlet`

**First Solution:**

**mySideDrawer.component.html**

```
<StackLayout tkMainContent>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</StackLayout>
```

**Home.component.ts**

```
<GridLayout rows="*" height="1500px">
    <MySideDrawer #mySideDrawer>
        <Label fontSize="20" text="Component 1"></Label>
            <Button text="OPEN" (tap)="onOpen()"></Button>
            <Button text="Go to component 2" [nsRouterLink]="['/home/comp2']"></Button>
    </MySideDrawer>
</GridLayout>
```

full demo:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=YmqaP3

**Second Solution:**

```
<RadSideDrawer>
    <StackLayout tkDrawerContent backgroundColor="gray">
       <!-- Side bar content -->
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout tkMainContent>
        <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
    </StackLayout>

</RadSideDrawer>
```